How would I unlock bitlocker drive
I have a bitlocker drive I would like to unlock, i didn't setup a bitlockker so I don't know what options were used, I also don't have bitlocker password or recovery key
I can boot into windows 10 fine, but sadly I only have the user password, so I cannot turn off bitlocker on the drive without admin password
Is it possible to extraxt the key somehow or turn off bitlocker with user password?
This is a dell computer that uses Secure boot, but I did find in the bios, I can upload my own key to it (so I could sign something to boot before windows if I need to)

Have you see the Microsoft article Find your BitLocker recovery key?

but I can get into my computer fine, bitlocker doesn't prompt me for any key (it auto unlocks I guess)
I just cannot turn it off, because I have no admin rights

Is it Windows 10 Home or Windows 10 Professional? Can you ask the person you got the computer from for an administrator account name and password?


Is it possible to extraxt the key somehow or turn off bitlocker with user password?

Most likely not. It's part of the security model in a sense – the whole auto-unlock feature remains secure only as long as the OS enforces its own account security.
It might be possible to boot into a Windows Recovery image, though, and find a way to bypass its password checks. I remember some people on Reddit using WinRE to fix the CrowdStrike issue last month, but IIRC it still required the admin password...

This is a dell computer that uses Secure boot, but I did find in the bios, I can upload my own key to it (so I could sign something to boot before windows if I need to)

That's not going to work, as BitLocker binds the TPM sealed key to PCR7 which tells it exactly which Secure Boot certificates were involved in verifying the boot process (and even when turning on BitLocker for the first time, will insist on only seeing Microsoft certificates in the PCR7 log). Whether you sign something yourself or use a "third-party signed" Linux distro, the PCR7 log will be different and will prevent the TPM from unsealing the BitLocker key.

hmm interesting, I thought bitlockers only purpose is to prevent a person without a password to not be able to acsess someones files
while I have the password (although not the admin one) and I cannot turn it off
is there a way to get the key from ram? (I know F-Secure had a usb key, but I didn't find any image of it)
